# Can I add files to directories.bin dynamically through npm script BEFORE npm process the files inside directories.bin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'm trying to create a script that will download some binaries and put them in a folder e.g `cli`. That folder will be the same used on package.json for `directories.bin`:

```
...
"directories": {
   "bin": "cli"
}
```

So I need a script (I've tried with `preinstall`) executing on `npm install` and **BEFORE** npm "copy" all the binaries inside `cli` folder to `node_modules/.bin`. Using `preinstall` doesn't work, it seems the files are added AFTER the `cli` folder is processed by `npm`

Comment: What is not working exactly? You could just make a shell script that copies the binaries to `node_modules/.bin` on `preinstall` no?

Comment: Hi @BasvanderLinden, I guess I can directly copy the binaries to `node_modules/.bin` but I'll be doing `npm`'s job. Also if leave it to `npm` and copy a `.exe` to the folder pointing on `directories.bin` it generates on Windows extensions `.cmd` and `.ps1` for command prompt and PowerShell respectively.

Comment: I'm looking for a script that copy de binaries to the folder `directories.bin` are pointing BEFORE `npm` copy those to `node_modules/.bin`